# configure Courier IMAP - multiple users and folder sync

Tags: email, imap

I would like to configure the IMAP Settings of my Courier mail server do to the following things:

1) Allow concurrent connections from multiple clients by the same user.  (For instance Computer, mobile phone and pad...)

2) Turn on auto folder synchronisation so that the different clients all share the same folders.

3) Allow the creation of custom directories in the main directory.

Which of these things can be acchieved and how? I could not find any of these things in the
/etc/courier-imap/imapd - but maybe I just understood the descriptions wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, this is a site for programming questions.  For server configuration and help, please try serverfault.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that! I was already wondering why i couldnt use courier as a tag. :)

Comment: You should delete your question then. :)